python/selenium: how to use any_of with element_to_be_clickable
My selenium-project needs to wait for a certain element of three to become clickable.
I am using this code atm:
LOC1 = (By.ID, "ID1")
LOC2 = (By.ID, "ID2")
LOC2 = (By.ID, "ID3")
def get_correct_el(self):
    def wait_for_el():
        return self.robot.wait.until(
            EC.any_of(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(LOC1),
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(LOC2),
                EC.element_to_be_clickable(LOC3),
            )
        )
    el = wait_for_el()
    while el != self.driver.find_element(*LOC1):
        el.click()
        el = wait_for_el()

The code works, but the linter complains:
Argument of type "(WebDriverOrWebElement) -> (WebElement | Literal[False])" cannot be assigned to parameter "expected_conditions" of type "(D@any_of) -> T@any_of" in function "any_of"
  Type "(WebDriverOrWebElement) -> (WebElement | Literal[False])" cannot be assigned to type "(Unknown) -> WebElement"
    Function return type "WebElement | Literal[False]" is incompatible with type "WebElement"
      Type "WebElement | Literal[False]" cannot be assigned to type "WebElement"
        "Literal[False]" is incompatible with "WebElement"PylancereportArgumentType
(function) def element_to_be_clickable(mark: WebElement | Tuple[str, str]) -> ((WebDriverOrWebElement) -> (WebElement | Literal[False]))
An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.

element is either a locator (text) or an WebElement

Is this an error that I can safely ignore or am I using these functions incorrectly?
Thanks!
edit: It's any_of complaining about the types, not element_to_be_clickable.
any_of expects: *expected_conditions: Callable[[D], T]
element_to_be_clickable returns: Callable[[WebDriverOrWebElement], Union[Literal[False], WebElement]]
I understand, that the the signatures don't match, my question is how I am supposed to use any_of with element_to_be_clickable.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code snippet? This seems like an overly complicated way to achieve it... comparing elements, etc.

@JeffC
LOC2 and LOC3 are buttons on popups that may or may not show (and block the webpage). LOC1 is the element I actually want to click. So the logic is to wait for one of them to become clickable and if it is LOC1 then all is fine, if it is any of the other two then click it and continue to wait for LOC1.

This is a warning.
You pass an argument in element_to_be_clickable that does not correspond to the required type. Something like this can lead to unexpected behavior (which is difficult to predict).

It could be that the argument is a function that returns a WebElement instance or False, but the compiler expects a function that returns a WebElement instance.

I don't see from your code what arguments you're passing. But if I were you I would fix it.

I amended my question. The issue doesn't lie with LOC1-3 (from my understanding), but with the return type of element_to_be_clickable.
